# How to auto-scroll when text is added to my JScrollPane/JArea?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, caret

I have a `JTextArea` in a small app that shows all the exceptions `e.getMessage` and other things. However,  the JScrollPane does not show the latest results. I have to manually scroll it so that I could see what has just happened.

I want it to be exactly like Eclipse Console

How can I set up the cursor ?

Here is my code

```
publiv void createGUI)( {

                JTextArea progress = new JTextArea("");

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(progress);
        jsp.setBounds(320, 10, 280, 300); 
        j.add(jsp) ;

        JScrollBar max = jsp.getVerticalScrollBar() ;
        max.setValue(max.getMaximum() ) ;        // I tried this as suggested by Yasmani Llanes, but it did not work
...
```

Comment: Do you want to set cursor ?

Comment: Please post your code, but if you're using a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/ScrollPane.html) you can call [setScrollPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/ScrollPane.html#setScrollPosition%28java.awt.Point%29).

Comment: Note that the Eclipse Console uses `SWT` not `Swing`

Comment: How are you setting the new text of the progress control?

Comment: DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) text.getCaret(); and caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

Comment: @mKorbel that would make a good answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the caret position at the end of the text:

```
progress.setCaretPosition(progress.getText().length())
```

The following example works for me:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea txtTest;

    Test() {
        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        txtTest = new JTextArea();
        pane.setViewportView(txtTest);
        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnAddText = new JButton("Add Text");
        btnAddText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtTest.setText(txtTest.getText() + "\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sagittis id nibh vel rhoncus. ");

                String text = txtTest.getText();

                txtTest.setCaretPosition(text != null ? text.length() : 0);
            }
        });
        this.add(btnAddText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();             
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this is exactly waht i need ~!!~

Answer (score 2):

Get a hold of the scroll bar in your `JScrollPane` and scroll it to the bottom:

```
JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
```

Comment: How should this interact with the user?  Would they be able to scroll up if they want to?